Center a large picture both vertically and horizontally on a full page
I have a figure with a large size of 1860 x 2983. I would like to center it as large as possible with a small margin. Currently, I am using the following code:
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.png}
This makes the figure barely fit on the page, with little white space below the figure, while it starts where normal text would start.


Welcome to TeX.SE.


I would like to center [the image] [and make it] as large as possible with a small margin.

I suggest you place the image inside a figure[p] environment, as follows. (The framelines around the image shown below appear because the code loads the showframe package.)

\documentclass[demo]{article} % delete 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{showframe} % omit in real document

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p] % for vertical centering
\centering        % for horizontal centering
\includegraphics[width=0.99\textwidth,   % if you prefer: `1\textwidth`
                 height=0.99\textheight, % if you prefer: `1\textheight`
                 keepaspectratio]%
                {image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Thanks! By adding \usepackage{showframe} I saw the margins were restricting the figure. With the following code I was enable to get what I wanted. \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}   \begin{figure}   \centering   \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{image.png}   \caption{Enter Caption}   \label{fig:enter-label}   \end{figure}  \restoregeometry

@quinten - You're welcome. I hadn't realized that changing the whole page geometry was an additional degree of (design) freedom you had. :-) FWIW, left=1cm,right=1cm, top=2cm,bottom=2cm may be expressed more succinctly as hmargin=1cm, vmargin=2cm. Given the narrow margins, you may also want to consider inserting \thispagestyle{empty} between \end{figure} and \restoregeometry.

If you want to overlap the margins, the easiest way is to use the [overlay] option of tikz.  Otherwise you have to compute the margins and figure out where the center of the page is relative to the center of the text area.  (Doable, but more work.)  Note that it takes two runs to get the location right.
It is important to make figure think you have filled the text area, otherwise it may try to add another figure on the same page.  The tikzpicture itself takes up no space (like \hbox{}).
\documentclass{article} % delete 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}% remove page number
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}% fill text area
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node at (current page.center) {%
      \includegraphics[width=8in, height=10in]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

