Center first page title in exactly the middle of the page
I have the following code to create the front cover of a book:
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove page number

\title{\fontsize{34pt}{34pt}\selectfont{ This is the title }}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \vspace*{-4.3cm}
    \maketitle
    \vspace*{11.5cm}
    \fontsize{34pt}{34pt}\selectfont{ Author }
\end{document}

My problem is that the horisontal center of the text is shifted, it isn't exactly at the horisontal center of the page.
I have been trying to find out how but without success. Can someone help me please?

Book covers are typically made on a separate size paper which are cut to fit.  Paperback covers put the front and back on one sheet (like a leaflet).

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/717561/center-a-large-picture-both-vertically-and-horizontally-on-a-full-page

To get an exact placement of your texts, it is best to use tikz and tikzpagenodes packages
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe=true}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    
    \node[anchor=base, opacity=1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (current page text area.center) {\huge This is the title};
    
    \node[anchor=base, opacity=1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (current page text area.south) {\huge Author};
    
    \draw[opacity=0.25] (current page text area.west)--(current page text area.east) (current page text area.north)--(current page text area.south);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}


Minor correction to shift the text: \node[anchor=base, opacity=1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at ($(current page text area.south)+(0,2)$) {\fontsize{34pt}{34pt}\selectfont{Author}};

I take it that you want "This is the title" to be centered both vertically and horizontally on the page and that "Author" should show up at the very bottom.
If these assumptions are on target, the following solution may be of interest to you. The framelines are drawn because I've loaded the showframe package.

\documentclass[11pt,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % suppress page number
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{34pt}{34pt}\selectfont  
    \centering
    \phantom{Author}
    
    \vspace*{\fill}
    This is the title 
    
    \vspace*{\fill}
    Author 
\end{document}


Thank you. But this answer is no different than mine. The sentences do not take the exact center of the page as it does not take margins into consideration..

@ellat - Usually, when one talks about "centering" text vertically or horizontally, it's with regard to the textblock, not the physical sheet of paper -- about which you've provided no information so far. Is the paper size supposed to be US Letter, A4, or something else? It would also help if you provided actionable information about how wide the margins are supposed to be. Or should memoir's default margin and margin-paragraph settings be observed?

Okay, apologies. I'm simply trying to design a cover page to a book. I would like the title to take the exact center of the page (there shouldn't be any margins). The current code above shifts the text slightly due to margins. This is my problem..

@ellat - But what's the paper size?

The paper size I'm using is 184mmx120mm, I did not think this information is relative this is why I did not include it. Thanks.
