Filling a page with colour
I'm trying to fill part of one page of my project with some colour. My code is the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\definecolor{azulani}{RGB}{0,71,171}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[azulani] ($(current page.north west)-(0cm,17cm)$) rectangle (current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

However, it does not fill the entire rectangle, a little part of the left doesn't seem to be covered.  Thanks in advance!

I can not reproduce the problem. You need to post a complete compilable example starting with \documentclass{... and ending with \end{document}

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: inner sep is only for nodes, an not rectangle.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

try https://ctan.org/pkg/clrstrip

@hpekristiansen You are of course right!

@hpekristiansen edited it! Thanks

So,ewjat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/717561/center-a-large-picture-both-vertically-and-horizontally-on-a-full-page

The problem can not be reproduced. Your code does not compile.
Adding \usetikzlibrary{calc} gives:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\definecolor{azulani}{RGB}{0,71,171}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[azulani] ($(current page.north west)-(0cm,17cm)$) rectangle (current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


